# The existence of onto function of a set to its power sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Cantor’s Theorem: Given any set $A$, there does not exist a function $f : A → P(A)$ that is onto.
>
> The book that I am reading says:
>   Assume, for contradiction, that, $f$ : $A → P (A)$ is onto. Where $f(a)$ is a particular subset of $A$, for each element of A. To arrive at a contradiction, we will produce a subset B ⊆ A that is not equal to f(a) for any $a ∈ A$.
>
> $B = ${ a ∈ A : a does not belong to f ( a ) }.
>
> Now assume that there is some $a'$ ∈ $B$, then $a'$ does NOT belong to $f(a')$, then $a'$ does NOT belong to $B$, hence contradiction. Similarly for the case when $a'$ doesn't belong to $B$.

The question:
Having $a'$ ∈ $B$, then $a'$ does NOT belong to $f(a')$ why does it imply that $a'$ does NOT belong to $B$? After all it is the definition of $B$, to consist the elements that does NOT belong to $f(a)$ for any $a$ from $A$. In this case $a'$.

P.S. I saw similar questions about Cantor's Theorem but didn't find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contradiction arises if you assume that $B=f(a)$ for some $a\in A$.

Then: $$a\in f(a)\iff a\notin f(a)$$ The conclusion is that no such $a$ exists.

Comment: But the assumption is that B = { a ∈ A : a does not belong to f ( a ) } and by this assumption if a' does not belong to f(a'), then it belongs to B. Can you, please, explain?

Comment: And if $B=f(a)$ and $a'∈B$ doesn't it mean that  $a'∈f(a')$? However, by assumption it does not belong to $f(a')$. Is this the contradiction? So, there is an additional assumption by setting $B=f(a)$?

Comment: The main assumption must be that some $a\in A$ exists such  that $f(a)=\{x\in A\mid x\notin f(x)\}$. That leads to $a\in f(a)\iff a\notin f(a)$ which is absurd. Do you see that? I rather do not judge about the book you are reading. Maybe you misinterpreted.

Comment: Ok, in words $f(a)$ maps any element $x$ from $A$ to its subset(power set) such that this element does not belong to its subset $f(x)$. Is my interpretation right?

Comment: In words: assume that a surjective function $f:A\to\wp(A)$ exists. Now define $B:=\{x\in A\mid x\notin f(x)\}$. Since  $f$ is surjective there must be an $a\in A$ with $f(a)=B$. That however leads to $a\in f(a)\iff a\notin f(a)$ which is absurd.  So the assumption that a surjective function $f:A\to\wp(A)$ exists must be false.